# How to compare two lists in the same dictionary and see if a value is in both

Tags: python

I am fairly new to Python and would appreciate some help for a project I am working on for work.
I have a dictionary of lists and want to traverse the dictionary and check if any values of the lists are the same.

```
dict={'one':[1,2,3], 'two':[3,4,5], 'three':[5,6,7]}
```

I need to check the list value of 'one' and check to see if in 'two' and 'three', then check 'two' values are in 'three' and so on.  Then I need to print out the key and values that are the same.
ie.

```
3 - 'one' 'two'
5 - 'two' 'three'
```

Not sure the best way to do this.

Comment: oh you changed the problem statement ... like almost entirely

Answer (score 4):

You can take the combination of keys using [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) and find the itersection of values for pairwise keys:

```
from itertools import combinations

dct = {'one':[1,2,3], 'two':[3,4,5], 'three':[5,6,7]}

for k1, k2 in combinations(dct, 2):
    s = set(dct[k1]).intersection(dct[k2])
    for x in s:
        print("{2} - '{0}' '{1}'".format(k1, k2, x))
```

---

```
3 - 'one' 'two'
5 - 'two' 'three'
```

Comment: lol except he totally changed the problem statement (+1 all the same... I had almost this same thing typed up but ...)

Comment: @czach123 If you find this answer useful, you may consider accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

A nice way to do it in pure python is to iterate over all possible values in the resulting lists. Create a dictionary that maps each value to the keys associated with it.

```
d ={'one':[1,2,3], 'two':[3,4,5], 'three':[5,6,7]}

results = dict()

for key in d.keys():
    for value in d[key]:
        if value in results:
            results[value].append(key)
        else:
            results[value] = [key]
```

Now, when you call results, you will get a dictionary that looks like

```
{1: ['one'],
 2: ['one'],
 3: ['two', 'one'],
 4: ['two'],
 5: ['three', 'two'],
 6: ['three'],
 7: ['three']}
```

We can then go through the results and only print out the ones with multiple associated keys.

```
for number, strings in results.items():
    if len(strings) > 1:
        print number, strings
```

Giving you:

```
3 ['two', 'one']
5 ['three', 'two']
```

This way of doing it should be fast since it's linear with respect to the total length of the combined lists from the original dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

```
for v in set(sum(dict.values(), [])):
    keys = [k for k in dict if v in dict[k]]
    print("{:d} - {:s}".format(v, "'" + "' '".join(keys) + "'"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new_data = {}
data_dict = {'one':[1,2,3], 'two':[3,4,5], 'three':[5,6,7]}

for key,values in data_dict.items():
   for value in values:
        new_data.setdefault(value,[]).append(key)

print new_data
```

I guess is how i would do it... theres trickier and cooler ways but this is simple to understand and i think the smallest big-O

Answer (score 0):

You can turn the dictionary into a list of tuples then 
iteratively compare the first tuple in the list to the
remaining tuples in the list like this:

```
data = {'one':[1,2,3], 'two':[3,4,5], 'three':[5,6,7]}

search = list(data.items())

while search:
    target = search.pop(0)
    for candidate in search:
         for item in target[1]:
            if item in candidate[1]:
                 print (item, target[0], candidate[0])
3 one two
5 two three
```